# Why I do not have the values in main activity if I set the variable?

Tags: java, android

So I have the following classes and functions and etc.

```
public class shitson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
private DiaryActivity activity = new DiaryActivity();

public shitson(DiaryActivity diaryActivity) {
    activity = diaryActivity;
}

protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    String url2 = "https://..............";
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {

            JSONArray urlOfURLs = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            for (int i = 0; i < urlOfURLs.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JSONURL = urlOfURLs.getJSONObject(i);
                String url = JSONURL.getString("url");
                tmp.add(url);
                activity.addItem(url);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    super.onPostExecute(strings);
    activity.setList(tmp);
}

public void writeout() {
    for (String i : tmp) {
        Log.e("-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-", i);
    }
}
}
```

Main activity:

```
public class DiaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> allURL = new ArrayList<>();

    public void writeOut() {
        for (String i : allURL) {
            Log.e("123456789", i);
        }
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.allURL = list;
    }

    private void fireYourAsyncTask() {
        new shitson(this).execute();
        writeOut();
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
    fireYourAsyncTask();
}
```

I build up the "tmp" list but after the activity.setList(tmp) I do not get any data in the main activity. In the shitson.java the "tmp" list has all items but the setList function is not working so I can not work with the list... While my application depends on the informations I get from json... I could not make anything useful on my app because of this bug...

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is an asynchronous call (pretty obvious from the name?), meaning that it won't block the UI thread. You are calling writeOut() immediately after executing shitson. So the allUrl array list is still empty(while shitson is performing the json operation on another thread). Move the writeOut() call to the onPostExecute of shitson:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    super.onPostExecute(strings);
    activity.setList(tmp);
    activity.writeOut();
}
```